# Strings not stored in mongodb after post using expressjs

Tags: mongodb, angular, express, post, mongoose-schema

I have a MEAN stack application which I followed a tutorial to build and I got one string saving successfully to the database, When I tried to implement saving multiple strings to the database with the one call I get no errors but when I try retrieve the information or view it in the mongo shell there has been an element added with an object ID but the strings are blank? I've used console.log(); to follow he stings up until the post and they look correct.

The moongoose model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var muv = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    empId: {type: String, required: true},
    num: {type: String, required: true},
    job: {type: String, required: true},
});

schema.plugin(muv);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', schema);
```

The service for posting and getting:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Message } from "./message.model";

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getMessages(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/messages')
            .map( (data: Response) => {
                const extracted = data.json();
                const msgArray: Message[] = [];
                let message;
                for (let element of extracted.data) {
                    console.log(element.content);
                    message = new Message(element.content, element.content, element.content, element.content ,element.content);
                    msgArray.push(message);
                }
                return msgArray;
            });
    }

    saveMessage(message: Message): Observable<any> {
        console.log(message);
        const body = JSON.stringify(message);
        console.log(body);
        const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/message', body, {headers: headers});
    }
}
```

The component using the service:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Message } from "./message.model";
import { MessageService } from "./message.service";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'Employees',
  templateUrl: 'employees.component.html',
  providers: [MessageService]
})

export class EmployeesComponent { 

    messages: Message[] = [];

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

    onAddMessage() {
        const message = new Message('Jim','Smith','EP100','08710101010','Manager');
        this.messages.push(message);
        this.messageService.saveMessage(message)
            .subscribe(
                () => console.log('Success!'),
                error => console.error(error)
            );
    }
}
```

The POST:

```
router.post('/message', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.firstName);
    console.log(req.body.lastName);
    console.log(req.body.empId);
    console.log(req.body.num);
    console.log(req.body.job);

    var message = new Message({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        empId: req.body.empId,
        num: req.body.num,
        job: req.body.job
    });
    message.save(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Error while saving data!'
            });
        }
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Saved data successfully'
        });
    });
});
```

My mongodb record, the content was the first string and the last 5 undefined rows are when I tried to post the model above:

```
> db.messages.find().sort({_id:1});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c4436e02895f0e0404193d"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c4437102895f0e0404193e"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c4437202895f0e0404193f"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c4461f02895f0e04041940"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c4463302895f0e04041941"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c4463502895f0e04041942"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c4463b02895f0e04041943"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c4465802895f0e04041944"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c4467202895f0e04041945"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c4467c02895f0e04041946"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c45a7569709943d04cb033"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c4600e9674323310888acd"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c463d1baaac10b60663601"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c463d2baaac10b60663602"), "content" : " It worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c477780947a84580a2e0b0"), "content" : " It still worked!", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cfcd1e2f4cf920841d2f9f"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cfcfd42f4cf920841d2fa0"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cfd4527f1f8303783dacf8"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cfd5008c437e31a85b31e8"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cfd582bb3fb53f2cbf51e0"), "__v" : 0 }
```

Comment: Looks pretty good to me...did you happen to restart your express services after updating code (sorry if thats a stupid question, just being thorough)?

Comment: The problem is in this line i think `schema.plugin(muv)` remove this line and try without plogun ?

Comment: @LastJon as in close everything down and reopen nodejs? yes if so

Comment: @Babar Bilal tried it there same results

Comment: Please share your mongodb record

Comment: I added it there, if it means anything when I GET the data it logs as undefined in the console